# Get array from jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, autocomplete

I am using JQuery to autocomplete names from a remote database... this all works fine.

However, I want to also get ALL the information associated with that name from the autocomplete and save it to a php array...

Can anyone help?

This is my code for the autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#findname").autocomplete({
    source: "templates/search2.php?field=sire",
      minLength: 5 
  });
});
</script>
```

And here is how I call it...

```
<input type="text" name="name"  id = "findname" size="45"><br>
```

So, when I find the name I am looking for, which works fine, how can I return ALL the data for that named record and store to an array, to then call a modal with the data ?

Thanks

Comment: what does teh server returns to the templates/search2.php?field=sire request?

Comment: Currently I get this from the database

    $result = $db->query("SELECT distinct registeredName FROM     people WHERE registeredName like \"%".$term."%\"");
$field = 'registeredName';

And then I build the return JSON

    $array = array();   
    while ($data = $result ->fetch_object()){        
      $row_array['id'] = $data->id;        
      $row_array['value'] = $data->$field;         
      array_push($array, $row_array);    
      }     
    echo json_encode($array);

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question, you want to get the data of a worker to show in a modal, well, first you need to get all the data you want in a single call, not just the names, but also the mail, age or other atributes, then you save it in an object .

For example:

After you called the information, you should get something like this :

```
var workersData=[{name:"a1",mail:"m1",age:20},
{name:"a2",mail:"m2",age:20},
{name:"a3",mail:"m3",age:20},
{name:"a4",mail:"m4",age:20}];
```

Then you create a method to get all the names and put this array in the autocomplete input:

```
function listStringsFromArray(list, atribute) {
var arrayString = [];
if (list) {
    for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
        arrayString.push(list[index][atribute]);
    }
}
return arrayString;
}

$("#findname").autocomplete({
source: listStringsFromArray(workersData,"name"),
  minLength: 5 
});
```

Finally add a method for the input, so anytime it changes, to search for the rest of the data in the workers array and put the information where you want:

```
 $("#findname").keypress(function(e){
        fillDataModalWorker();      });

  function fillDataModalWorker(){
var workerName=$("#findname").val();
var mail,age;

    for (var index = 0; index < workersData.length; index++) {

        if(workersData[index]["name"]==workerName){
            mail=workersData[index]["mail"];
            age=workersData[index]["age"];
        $("#inputMailModal").val(mail);
        $("#inputAgeModal").val(age);
        break;
        }else{
            $("#inputMailModal").val("Worker´s information not found");
        $("#inputMailModal").val("Worker´s information not found");

        }
    }


 }
```

Hope it hepls.